# Using D3, I am trying to add and remove lines from a multi line chart when the legend is clicked

Tags: d3.js

I am able to get the legend to update(toggle a class on the legend) but on the chart, only the first instance of the ".line" class is updating.
Please have a look, it is very much appreciated:

```
var legend = d3.select("#legend1").append("svg")
          .attr("class", "legend")
          .selectAll("g")
          .data(z.domain().slice().reverse())
          .enter()
          .append("g")
          .on("click", function(){       
                 d3.select(this)
                  .classed("legendOption", d3.select(this)
                  .classed("legendOption") ? false : true),

                 d3.select(".line")
                   .classed("test", d3.select(".line")
                   .classed("test") ? false : true);
          ;})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use selectAll if you're selecting multiple elements of the same class. Also, if you post a JSFiddle or something similar it would be easier to understand what you're referring to.

Comment: Using SelectAll causes all the lines to disappear/reappear instead of just the line that corresponds with the legend item.

Comment: Could you possibly post a JSFiddle so I could take a look?

Comment: I just added the script in the jsfiddle as the data is from an internal source, I hope this will help, thanks in advance: https://jsfiddle.net/y1f6hk2z/

Comment: Ripped someone's bl.lock.org to use as an example, the code that should hopefully be of interest to you is on 87-94, https://jsfiddle.net/fgsbhqa3/. Use the key from the CSV data and assign it as the id to the paths you've created, you can then use it to select/deselect with the legend.

Comment: Woops just realised I put "self" instead of "d3.select("#" + key)" in the code, here's the correct version: https://jsfiddle.net/fgsbhqa3/1/.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it tomorrow when I'm back at work. I don't really understand the # and key part, but I'll give it a go

Comment: You know when you pass in the data from the CSV file, and you reference it by d.id, d.index, etc. If you set the 'id' attribute to the d.id from the data, then you can reference the path using the id. Assuming that the name of the legend is the same as the id stored in the CSV file then you can cross-reference which legend has been clicked with the corresponding path. If that makes more sense?

Comment: With regards to the '#', that's just letting d3js know that you're referring to the id attribute not the class. So for example to select an element with the id 'hi' you would do: d3.select('#hi'). Hope that helps, feel free to comment when you're back in work and I'll try to reply asap.

Comment: I added the id to the lines, so that they are now the same as the text in the legend but I'm still not able to make it work. I am trying to select it like "d3.select("#" + d.id")" but thats not working.

Comment: I assume the "d3.select("#" + d.id")" is in the .on("click", (function {}) for the legend? If so, you need to actually retrieve the id from the text of the legend using text(). You can't refer to it as d.id because it's not present in the click func.

Comment: So you should be doing something like this: "d3.select("#" + d3.select(this).text())" in the click function.

Comment: ok, so text was below the ".on" I have adjusted it to be above, in the code. the issue now seems to be that if the id of the line is more than one word, it doesn't work. example: if the label/id is "Construction" it works, but if its "Construction permits" it doesn't...any ideas? Thanks again, you're a big help

Comment: That's strange, I've just tried testing it on a fiddle and it seems to be working for me. Is the text of the legend and the id of the path definitely being set to the same thing? Try using console.log(line.attr('id')) and console.log(legend.text()) to make sure?

Comment: when I inspect in chrome and remove the space from the line and legend it works: "Constructionpermits"

Comment: console.log(legend.text()) - this pulls out the text but nothing from this -
 console.log(line.attr('id')) it says line.attr is not a function...

Comment: Just googled it, and it was quite stupid of me to suggest using the id attribute, apparently, it's invalid to use a space in the id tag. I'm sorry. I just found a fix. You can view it here: https://jsfiddle.net/v7qr4aer/2/

Comment: Basically, you would do this instead d3.select("[id='" + d3.select(this).text() + "']");

Comment: That's it, works beautifully, thanks for all the help, I really appreciate it

Comment: No problem man, glad to help. Hope the rest of your project goes well :).